# Calculate start-/end angle for Arc given horizontal width and length of Arc

Tags: trigonometry, angle, arc-length

Given the length $B$, horizontal width $C$ and the radius $R$, I need to calculate the start $(A)$ -/end $(A+\theta)$ angles.

So far I've got

$C=R(\cos(A)-\cos(A+\theta))$

where $\theta=B/R$

If I'm not mistaken, I need to isolate $A$ out in the form of $A=...$, which I am unable to do.

How do I isolate A? Am I thinking right?

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires the [sums to products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) formula.

$$\cos\theta-\cos\varphi=-2sin\left(\frac{\theta+\varphi}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\theta-\varphi}{2}\right)$$

Applying it to your formula you get:

$$C=R(\cos(A)-\cos(A+\theta))$$

$$\frac{C}{R}=-2\sin\left(\frac{A+A+\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-(A+\theta)}{2}\right)$$

$$\frac{C}{R}=-2\sin\left(\frac{2A+\theta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{-\theta}{2}\right)$$

$$2\sin\left(\frac{2A+\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{C}{R\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

$$\sin\left(\frac{2A+\theta}{2}\right)=\frac{C}{2R\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

$$\frac{2A+\theta}{2}=\arcsin\left(\frac{C}{2R\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)$$

$$A=\arcsin\left(\frac{C}{2R\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)-\frac{\theta}{2}$$